# How to get the .MDF / .LDF files location in case the database don't exist

Tags: sql-server, database, database-restore

I have a couple of tests servers and I am trying to drop each database and restore them using backup files located on a remote file system.

```
RESTORE DATABASE db_1 FROM DISK = '\\remote\file\path'
WITH REPLACE,
MOVE 'db_1' TO 'W:\Common1\Data\db_1.mdf',
MOVE 'db_1_log' TO 'W:\Common1\Logs\db_1_log.ldf'
```

This works fine if I give the correct location. The issue I am having is that not all test servers have the same .mdf and .ldf locations. I am able to query `select * from db_1.dbo.sysfiles` and get the locations but I am out of luck if the database doesn't exist.

Is there a way that I can get the correct .mdf and .ldf of a particular database in case the database doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [FILELISTONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) restore option to get the information (including the physical filename and path) for the files in the database backup.

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'path to your .bak'
```

You can dump this output to a table and dynamically create your restore commands from the information.